# Updating tail in doubly linked list

Tags: python, python-3.4, doubly-linked-list

I had a question about updating self.tail in my doubly linked list class specifically for my add_to_head method. I wrote a separate function to do this but I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing it. 
Here is a what I have:

```
def add_to_head(self, data):
    '''(input)-> None
    takes any type of input and creates a node with that input as data.
    Takes that node and adds it to the front of the list
    '''
    new_node = DLLNode(data)
    if self.head == None:
        self.head = self.tail = new_node
    else:
        self.head.prev = new_node
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node
    self.update_tail()

def update_tail(self):
    '''(DLLList)->None
    updates the tail of the DLLList
    '''
    current = self.head
    while current != None:
        current = current.next
    current = self.tail
```

This is assuming self.tail and self.head have been set to None when creating this class. Also the only time I call this function is when calling the add_to_head method because when I am adding to the end of the list I am already updating the tail. 
In what other ways could I have implemented this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking about here. When adding to the head of the list, the only time you'd care about the tail is when the list is empty, which you already take care of. If the list is not empty, then the tail does not need to be updated.

Comment: Also, your update_tail function currently does nothing.

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything in `update_tail`? It doesn't return anything, nor does it do any side effects.

Comment: Sorry about that. My init contains two variables self.head and self.tail. When I add an item to the front of the list I want to be able to keep track of self.tail. I realise now I should have changed the last line to self.tail = current first of all. I was just wondering if there was a different way to do it.

Comment: I just figured it out. I don't need the update tail function at all. As you said David, if the list is empty I need to update it and if it isn't my first assignment of tail to whatever value we input just stays the same. Thanks!